# Can not download excel file using requests python, I can't get the third step of posting request to download excel file. here is my try

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

### Here is my attempt to download excel file ##----------

How Do i make it work. Can someone please help me to fix last call

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://lijekovi.almbih.gov.ba:8090/SpisakLijekova.aspx"

useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76"

headers={
    "User-Agent":useragent
}
session = requests.session() #session 

r = session.get(url,headers=headers) #request to get cookies

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser") #parsing values
viewstate = soup.find('input', {'id': '__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value')
viewstategenerator =soup.find('input', {'id': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value')
eventvalidation =soup.find('input', {'id': '__EVENTVALIDATION'}).get('value')
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
cookie=""
for k,v in cookies.items():
    cookie+=k+"="+v+";"
cookie = cookie[:-1]
#header copied from the requests.
headers={
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76',
'X-KL-Ajax-Request':'Ajax_Request',
'X-MicrosoftAjax':'Delta=true',
'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
'Cookie':cookie
}

#post request data submission
data={
    'ctl00$smMain':'ctl00$MainContent$ReportGrid$ctl103$ReportGrid_top_4',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$MainContent$ReportGrid$ctl103$ReportGrid_top_4',
    '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewstategenerator,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventvalidation,
    '__ASYNCPOST':'true'


}

#need help with this part
result = requests.get(url,headers=headers,data=data)
print(result.headers)

data = {
    "__EVENTTARGET":'ctl00$MainContent$btnExport',
    '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,

    

}
#remove ajax request for the last call to download excel file
del headers['X-KL-Ajax-Request']
del headers['X-MicrosoftAjax']
del headers['X-Requested-With']


result = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,allow_redirects=True)
print(result.headers)
print(result.status_code)
#print(result.text)
with open("test.xlsx","wb") as f:
    f.write(result.content)
```

> > I am trying to export excel file without selenium help, but I am not able to get the last step. I need help to convert xmlhttprequest to pure requests using python without any selenium

Comment: Not sure why, but `result = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,allow_redirects=True)` gives error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What error are you getting?